# Darkmode for localhost:1234 and XML files

Tags: xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I

- Open xml documents in the Chrome Browser
- Doing a GET to a server via Chrome's address bar and receive an xml (for instance to something like localhost:1234/admin)

Then I get the background in white and the text mainly in black and purple. How can I change this so that the background is black and the text is white? I have tried using the chrome extension [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) to change the text and background but it won't apply to the domain localhost. I have also tried to find themes that gives a dark mode but have only found themes that is applied to all sites except the sites I specify. I want it to only apply to only the sites that I specify. How can I accomplish this?

Some possible solutions:

- Is there an extension that can accomplish this?
- Can this be done using stylish?
- Can I configure how Chrome opens xml files and which style it is using?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Gnome 3.18.5 and Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit).

Comment: But how? I tried both Stylus and Stylish and added things like
body { background: black !important; }
head { background: black !important; }
body { background: black; }
head { background: black; }
The theme appears when I enter localhost:1234 and I can apply it but no colors are changed...

Comment: Looks like both Stylish/Stylus couldn't style XML: the feature was [just added in Stylus](https://github.com/schomery/stylish-chrome/pulls) upcoming version. You can write your own userscript or extension that uses the same approach: create the `style` element with XML namespace.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail on how to accomplish this? I have managed to install the stylus from the repo you linked. How do I create a userscript or extension? How do I create a style element with a XML namespace. I haven't worked with HTML/CSS before.

Comment: If you use that development Stylus version, simply add a userstyle.